# How to Update UI from Button Event (or another Task)

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a button on my Xamarin iOS storyboard. This button triggers a method in my code. This method makes HttpClient web calls and I want to do status updates to the UI so the user knows whats going on.

Things like: "Sending", "Waiting for response", 
Timed out" etc.. I have a UITextView for this.

I've found a few pieces of code which claim to be able to do this, but so far none of the ones I have tried work. They only change the value of the TextView AFTER the entire button code has finished running. So it seems as if the new text values are queued up but not changed while the event is running.

The method I want to do this from is triggered like this:

```
ButtonRegister.TouchUpInside += EventSendRegisterRequest;
```

This does not work:

```
BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
   TextResponseRegister.Text = "Sending.";
});
```

Neither does this:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
   TextResponseRegister.Text = "Sending.";
});
```

Heres a simplified exampled of the code in `EventSendRegisterRequest`:

```
BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    TextResponseRegister.Text = "Sending.";
});

var c = new Communication.Communication();
var taskRegister = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    return await c.RegisterUserAsync(username, password, password, email);
});
taskRegister.Wait(5000);

BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    TextResponseRegister.Text = "Done.";
});
```

Only `Done` is ever displayed.

I want to be able to update the UI from any Task or UI Event. 
How do I do this?

Comment: Can you please share the full code via git or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorating the button event method with async like this:

```
private async void EventSendRegisterRequest(string username, string email, string password)
```

and then doing updates in that method like this:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
  TextResponseRegister.Text = "Sending.";
});
```

Solved my problems. Everything is now shown on the UI directly.